# Split a div inside bootstrap vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm struggling with a rather simple task but the lack of CSS experience is getting the better of me:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <span class="label label-info pull-right">Offline</span>
                <h5>Equipment Pass</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOffline.TransactionCount</h1>
                <small># of Transactions</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <span class="label label-success pull-right">Online</span>
                <h5>Equipment Pass</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOnline.TransactionCount</h1>
                <small># of Transactions</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <span class="label label-info pull-right">Offline</span>
                <h5>Visitor Pass</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassVisitorOffline.TransactionCount</h1>
                <small># of Transactions</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <span class="label label-success pull-right">Online</span>
                <h5>Visitor Pass</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassVisitorOnline.TransactionCount</h1>
                <small># of Transactions</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is a row on my view. There are many like it:

[image: BaseHTML]

I want to split the smallest div to show a second Heading1. Here is base HTML:

```
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOffline.TransactionCount</h1>
                <small># of Transactions</small>
                <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOffline.Income</h1>
                <small>Income generated</small>                 
            </div>
```

Target:
[image: Target]

I need to show more information and I see that the div card is empty on the right side. I want to split this div into two. Experimenting with bootstrap classes, the layout breaks.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: @ZimSystem Quoted: I want to split the smallest div to show a second Heading1. I have added more required info in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afer a bit of trial and error, i realized that the small grid class was the issue. I switched to class-md and got the desired result. So this:

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOffline.TransactionCount</h1>
    <small># of Transactions</small>
    <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOffline.Income</h1>
    <small>Income generated</small>                 
</div>
```

Became this:

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="no-margins">@Model.AirportPassEquipmentOnline.TransactionCount.ToString("N0")</h1>
            <small># of Transactions</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="no-margins">AED @Model.AirportPassEquipmentOnline.Income.ToString("N2")</h1>
            <small>Revenue generated</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```